# Magento 2 How to move product swatches container

Tags: magento2, product, swatches

I am trying to change product swatches container and putting it in detailed info tabs.But it move whole option block.How to move only swatches.Table is a watches image.

```
<move element="product.info.options.swatches" destination="full.area.tabs" before="-"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to get the swatches after quantity and before the add to cart button. Not perfect, but working for me.

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>





    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart-button.phtml

```
<div class="actions">
    <button type="submit"
            title="Add to cart"
            class="action primary tocart"
            id="product-addtocart-button">
        <span>Add to cart</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.options.swatches" destination="product.info.form.options" before="theme.product.addtocartbutton.only.container"/>
<move element="theme.product.addtocartbutton.only.container" destination="product.info.form.options" after="-"/>
```

Hope it works for you..!!